# Why is jquery sending GET request for a script tag that is dynamically loaded?

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, web

I use jquery's ajax method to dynamically load some html snippet from server, and insert the snippet in a div. Within the snippet are some `<script>` tags for external scripts.

I watched network activity in Chrome toolbar while making the ajax request, and found the GET requests for the script tags are appended with something like `?_=1234567890`. I also noticed
the initiator of the GET request is jquery. I know jquery does this for AJAX requests to avoid cached version being used, but I want the script to be cached.

What really surprised me is that the `<script>` tags are fetched by jquery with ajax. When you insert a `<script>` tag into DOM, should the browser be responsible for loading and executing it? Why is jQuery taking the action here?

If I skip jquery and use plain js to append a `<script>` tag to DOM, the browser will load and parse it, right? Why doesn't the browser do this and let jquery take over?

==============code=============

Code for loading the html snippet:

```
var url = "/"+modulename+"/settings/"+this.selectedProduct.id;
$.get(url, null, function(snippet){
  $("div#content").empty().html(snippet);
}
```

The html snippet:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://www.staticcdn.org/somelib.js"></script>

<script>
  <!--some html rendering code that depends on somelib-->
</script>
```

Comment: It's more a question of, why does jQuery take over and not let the browser do this?

Comment: It does if you set the cache option in $.ajax to false ?

Comment: if your `<script>` has a `src` attribute, then the srcipt will be loaded with GET from your browser (like all other external scripts)

Comment: Chrome includes jquery?  That is surprising.

Comment: @NeoWang Can you give a code snippet of your ajax request (like this  `$.ajax({...});`), please

Comment: @JeremyMiller No, sorry, my mistake. It is my own jquery sending the request.

Comment: @drkunibar I posted some code. The somelib.js is loaded by jquery and with ?_=231232132 appended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are in Chrome, here's a tip.  If you mouseover the Network call source, a popup will show with the stack heap at the time for the call.  Doing that on such a call exposes jquery.js:6717's _evalUrl being called on scripts the first time they are called on a page (setGlobalEval disables calling a second time for that script on the same page).

```
_evalUrl: function( url ) {
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "script",
        async: false,
        global: false,
        "throws": true
    });
}
```

Since that code does not use the cache option, you have a couple of options:

1. Use the unrecommended https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/ to set no caching for all calls, so you will have to override caching for all non-cached calls.  Did I mention **all** calls?
2. Edit the source.
3. Don't stress and leave things how they are.
4. A pure guess, but you could just fetch the content and insert it into the DOM yourself and deal with the rendering consequences on your own.

It appears that this is done as part of a structuring/sanitizing of the content being inserted into the DOM on a call.

Comment: Perhaps I will take 3. Jquery developers perhaps consider this a convenience, but they should offer some flexibility.

Comment: No prob.  Just wanted to give you all of your options.  Please remember to accept the answer that answers your question best.

Comment: One last question :) how does the browser know the script has been parsed by jquery? setGlobalEval function only tells jquery itself to not repeat evaluating it.

Comment: It doesn't.  When the script is loaded, it is handed off to be added to the DOM (you could make it not do that, ofc [option 4]).  The DOM control is by jQuery which then does it's thing of stripping out tags, fetching them, and re-inserting when fetched.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the jquery doc for ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and note the option `datatype`

> "script": Evaluates the response as JavaScript and returns it as plain text. Disables caching by appending a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL unless the cache option is set to true. Note: This will turn POSTs into GETs for remote-domain requests.

`$.get` use `$.ajax`. If you do not want the `?_=...` you have to call the `$.ajax` by yourself.

You also my have a look at the option `cache`

Comment: What I get with ajax is html (datatype), not pure script. But jquery takes the liberty to load the script tag within and evaluate it. In its doc, it says -- "html": Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM. -- But I didn't find any option to turn this off.

Comment: This is a feature of your browser. If you insert a `<script>` tag, the browser evaluate it.

Comment: That's exactly my point. The BROWSER should evaluate it, not jquery.

Comment: To clarify, the browser would evaluate it, but jQuery doesn't give it the choice.  jQuery is first inline as it fetches the content.  It chooses to parse it before handing it over to the browser by inserting it into the DOM.

Comment: If you use `dataType: "text"` you should receive the response as plain text and then you can handle it by yourself